# Problem when deploying project with web socket on Jetty 9.2.13.v20150730

Tags: websocket, jetty, omnifaces

I've experienced a problem while migrating an app from PrimeFaces 5.2 to 10.
This problem is related to migration of web socket implementation from Primefaces to Omnifaces.

The versions I'm using:

- PF: 10.0.0
- PF extensions: 10.0.6
- Omnifaces 2.7.7
- CDI 1.1
- JSF 2.2

I don't have anything fancy, just a simple PushBean which sends a message.

I've tried downgrading to PF8, but, as expected, the result is the same.

The configuration is made as requested in the documentation, in my web.xml file having this flag enabled:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.SOCKET_ENDPOINT_ENABLED</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

However, when I try to deploy my app to jetty, I'm receiving the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: OmniFaces failed to initialize! Report an issue to OmniFaces.
    at org.omnifaces.ApplicationListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationListener.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
```

.
.
.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot load platform configurator
    at javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig$Configurator.fetchContainerDefaultConfigurator(ServerEndpointConfig.java:123)
    at javax.websocket.server.DefaultServerEndpointConfig.<init>(DefaultServerEndpointConfig.java:85)
    at javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig$Builder.build(ServerEndpointConfig.java:301)
    at org.omnifaces.cdi.push.Socket.registerEndpointIfNecessary(Socket.java:1114)
    at org.omnifaces.ApplicationListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationListener.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
```

I'm guessing that there is something that I'm not doing right, but, I don't know exactly what is it.
Can you please, give a little hand?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually, it's that simple, but now, unfortunately, it isn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace / exception ...

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot load platform configurator
    at javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig$Configurator.fetchContainerDefaultConfigurator(ServerEndpointConfig.java:123)
    at javax.websocket.server.DefaultServerEndpointConfig.<init>(DefaultServerEndpointConfig.java:85)
    at javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig$Builder.build(ServerEndpointConfig.java:301)
```

This is coming from the `javax.websocket` API jar, when it attempts to find the Server Container Default Configuration (in other words, the implementation specific defaults, which would be Jetty)

If you are running Jetty, you need to be including the jetty support jar for `javax.websocket.server` in your classpath.

Which on Jetty 9.2.x would be the `javax-websocket-server-impl-<ver>.jar` file (and associated dependencies).

Per @BalusC, omnifaces is just a web-fragment deployed in your WAR's `WEB-INF/lib`.

That means you have to enable support for `websocket` on the Jetty server side.

For standalone (using `${jetty.base}` and `${jetty.home}` split) this means enabling the correct module for your version of Jetty.

| Jetty ver | WebSocket spec | Module |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jetty 8.x and older | n/a | n/a |
| Jetty 9.0.x | n/a | n/a |
| Jetty 9.1.x | `javax.websocket` (beta) | `websocket` |
| Jetty 9.2.x - 9.4.x | `javax.websocket` 1.0 | `websocket` |
| Jetty 10.0.x | `javax.websocket` 1.1 | `websocket-javax` |
| Jetty 11.0.x | `jakarta.websocket` 2.0 | `websocket-jakarta` |

To do that you'll use the command line.

*Jetty 9.x*

```sh
[~]$ cd /path/to/my-jetty-base
[my-jetty-base]$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-home/start.jar 
   --add-to-start=websocket
```

*Jetty 10+*

```sh
[~]$ cd /path/to/my-jetty-base
[my-jetty-base]$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-home/start.jar 
   --add-module=websocket-javax
```

Comment: I don't have experience with omnifaces, either. I'm using standalone jetty installation. In the file start.ini, the module websocket is added. Adding javax-websocket-server-impl-<ver>.jar in my pom.xml file just made the hole deeper, meaning that, at deployment, another jar was missing, jetty-server. After adding this (knowing that it is not ok), I have another problem, which I don't think it's relevant. I still think that I need to configure something, but I don't know what/where

Comment: The `javax-websocket-server-impl-<ver>.jar` is a server component, not ever meant to be used in a WAR with `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: OmniFaces is definitely not internally using Jetty or any other HTTP server in embedded mode (I am creator of OmniFaces). So the "just a library as part of a normal WAR" part goes on (OmniFaces is essentially a web-fragment library).

Comment: I'll update my answer then.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I was able to start the server without any problems! I didn't expect it to be so strange, because, in PF5.2, the socket worked as intended. The websocket module was already added in start.ini.